# How to parse cookies in txt file, for each different domain?

Tags: python-3.x

i need to ask how i can parse cookies from txt file but raggrup it for domain, in my txt i have like:

```
www.kyoceradocumentsolutions.es TRUE    /   TRUE    1715436652  terms-of-use    true
.kyoceradocumentsolutions.es    TRUE    /   TRUE    1718460926  _ga_Y1KGRYFV0P  GS1.1.1683907814.1.1.1683908126.0.0.0
accounts.google.com TRUE    /   FALSE   1686990272  OTZ 7035025_48_52_123900_48_436380
ogs.google.com  TRUE    /   FALSE   1686990266  OTZ 7035024_48_52_123900_48_436380
.google.com TRUE    /intl   TRUE    1718958270  _ga GA1.2-2.894878828.1684405470
.google.com TRUE    /intl   TRUE    1718958270  _ga_3WTQFP9ECQ  GS1.1-2.1684405470.1.0.1684405470.0.0.0
accounts.google.com FALSE   /   FALSE   1718958308  ACCOUNT_CHOOSER AFx_qI6iwd_j01-dk4MosTlZx_nE2Ar8qt0A7gYqV2M6p8lG6rKjQKqFilvrOld-iyRD7hBwp7s8zJVOZT_xvpe6he1me1BvYGw1xj_WMVO6e3FuLT8rFCLcJPMcHEkvTNH_-1S889-e
.google.es  TRUE    /   TRUE    1718958323  APISID  ZgBj3gBNrTqUKzB1/AWvl5OdibUyflSaBK
.youtube.com    TRUE    /   TRUE    1718958323  APISID  ZgBj3gBNrTqUKzB1/AWvl5OdibUyflSaBK
.google.es  FALSE   /   TRUE    1718958323  HSID    AheMSVSw0MoFyfrrE
.youtube.com    FALSE   /   TRUE    1718958323  HSID    AheMSVSw0MoFyfrrE
.google.es  FALSE   /   FALSE   1700209523  NID 511=pRdxSLAWx0Fs9pSfV0YoIdqRTJpTgIWzYZqrReCNkCFnTU4BRBE87r7JUsUGBhDVC7rQ1QmMV-1VUqjMBBSj2za-d_BGOHkiIcf-2XQvGLvVG07EoPL8FknhyuYEOYOBBem5HatjCgeVIBqWu0gn8rvtzQMqELo7PlkesM2bFIg
myaccount.google.com    FALSE   /   FALSE   1718958309  OSID    WwhAnHR2iVI3QGXqH1VMySpwpPwi-b1gz7_Q8TAJIC_LDixGHeHKdgf8y3OrUptiKQGfjQ.
```

I use this for import in my script the cookies:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from time import sleep

    def read_cookies(p = 'cookies.txt'):
        cookies = []
        with open(p, 'r') as f:
            for e in f:
                e = e.strip()
                if e.startswith('#'): continue
                k = e.split('\t')
                if len(k) < 3: continue # not enough data
                # with expiry
                cookies.append({'name': k[-2], 'value': k[-1], 'expiry': int(k[-3]})
        return cookies    
    # import cookies into selenium webdriver (to authenticate)
    def run():
        cookies = read_cookies()
        print ('[+] Read {} cookies'.format(len(cookies)))
        print (cookies)
        d = webdriver.Chrome()
        d.get('https://facebook.com')
        sleep(2)
        print(d.get_cookies())
        # adding cookies
        for c in cookies: d.add_cookie(c)
        print ('')
        print ('[+] Added cookies')
        print(d.get_cookies())
        d.get('https://facebook.com')
        sleep(50)
    def main():
        print ('[+] Selenium cookies importer')
        try: run()
        except Exception as ex: print ('[!] Error: {}'.format(ex))
        finally: print ('[+] Finished !')
    main()
```

The problem in my case is when i import the cookies i imoport every cookies on same domain, and this is problem because for import i need cookies for a single domain, example all domain *.google.com only for google, all cookies for *.kyoceradocumentsolutions.es for  kyoceradocumentsolutions.es atd atd...

Thanks for any help P.